# Shutdown a machine after backup if a file does not exist

Tags: powershell, azure-batch

I want to shut down many machines if the Backup is successfully finished. My Backup application has a option, shut down the machine after job is finished.

But it should be going down if a file does not more exits any more. For example:
We have a file named "swmw.obj", that file is deleted after the compiler is finished.

Is there any way to write a batch file or Power shell script to see if the "swmw.obj" does not exist anymore and the backup is finished, the machine should be going down?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
if(Test-path $FilePath -PathType leaf)
 {
    Stop-Computer -ComputerName xxx -Force -Credential <variable-for-credential>
 }
```

While working with Jenkins I found it's best to schedule a shutdown, rather than call it from powershell directly.
This can be a simple .bat script or a command like
`shutdown -s -t 60`

Comment: No I did not. But where can I set my file swmw.obj? and what is that <variable-for-credential>? I know that command shutdown -s -t 60, but it should be working with my file, if my file does not exist, the computer should be down

Comment: `$FilePath` is what you're looking for to set.